# Can i add sub route in Route::get?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I need control sub route by User Config

- i can't get request/route parameters on Route::group
- middleware run after Route::group
- Can't Include file sub route in Route::get

How do you do.

Example.

**Route.php**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/{user}'], function () { 

    Route::group(['prefix' => '/map'], function () { require app_path('map.route.php'); });
    Route::group(['prefix' => '/contact'], function () { require app_path('contact.route.php'); });

    Route::group(['prefix'=>'/'], function(){

      $user = \App\User::find($user);
       if( $user -> first_page )
       {
        require app_path($user -> first_page.'.route.php');
       }

    });

});
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be wrong here, but how about this (I added $user to the function)

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => '/{user}'], function ($user) { 

Route::group(['prefix' => '/map'], function () { require app_path('map.route.php'); });
Route::group(['prefix' => '/contact'], function () { require app_path('contact.route.php'); });

Route::group(['prefix'=>'/'], function($user){

  $user = \App\User::find($user);
   if( $user -> first_page )
   {
    require app_path($user -> first_page.'.route.php');
   }

});

});
```